# Regex PHP question

Tags: php, regex

Not gonna lie, I'm terrible at regex.

How would I be able to do this guys:

```
$string = '>Data 1-23</a>';
$string = '>Datkl3</a>';
$string = '>RA Ndom</a>';
```

And pull out the "Data 1-23" from inside the above string using regex? And if I have multiple ones of this, how would I be able to put all of the matched strings into an array?

Comment: It would help if you gave multiple example strings and the result you were after.  I mean, given this single example, doing a $string =~ s/>//g; seems like it would suffice, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks htw, was a stupid mistake forgetting that, even I know about code LOL. Thanks again

Comment: Are you trying to pull out the literal string "Data 1-23", or get the contents of all the "a" tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
  $string = ">Data 1-23</a>";
  $pattern = '/>([^<]*)</a>/';
  preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
?>
```

Should give you what you want, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for the text in hyperlinks your best bet is [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Here's a quick example:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.com/');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
  echo $element->innertext . '<hr/>';
```

Parsing the DOM tree gives much more reliable results than a simple regexp

Hope that helps!